# how to show facebook like box on hover in Opera browser

Tags: jquery, facebook, opera

I have following script, which makes showing "Facebook like box" when hover on button with .trigger class:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".trigger").hover(function(){
        $(".panel").show("fast");
        return false;
});
$("#container").hover(function(){
        $(".panel").hide("fast");
        return false;
});
});
```

Inside of .panel div I put generated facebook like box code.
This is working fine in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, IE8, IE7 and even in IE6. 
But in Opera browser the box is empty. Its not showing Facebook panel. However this is working fine with any other content.

I will be gratefull for any help.

Answer (score 0):

This link might make your work easier.

http://defunkt.io/facebox/

Facebox is a jquery plugin and works really well. Have been using it for a few months now.

Comment: that link goes somewhere else now

Answer (score 0):

You can try to replace the jQuery

```
document.ready
```

by the DOM feature

```
window.onload
```

The ready event occurs after the HTML document has been loaded, while the onload event occurs later once everything has been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

[Disclosure: I work for Opera, on QA and site compatibility]

I guess you're running into some known bugs in Facebook's connect.js library. Is the content in the box going to require that you're logged in to your Facebook account? If so, you are probably seeing this:
http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=13624

I hope Facebook will fix it, but we're also considering using Opera's site patching mechanisms to fix the script's bugs while we are waiting for a FB fix.